# Algorithm for packing circles within a circle?

Tags: algorithm, layout, computational-geometry

I want to pack a circle with sub circles of equal size so as to maximize the number of sub circles or minimize the space between sub circles. Ideally the algorithm should be able to parametrize the max/min number of sub circles required or the min/max spacing between sub circles?

Is this or a variant of this a well studied problem esp. in computation geometry or layout algorithms? If so what are some well algorithms for attacking this problem

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the constraints. If the inner circles can be any size, and the goal is to pack as many as possible, I'd start with size zero. If the question is "what portion of the larger circle can be packed?" there is a know solution: .906 as the size of inner circles approaches zero. Can you clarify the size constraints?

Comment: No effective algo exists.  It is very nontrivial problem.  Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general solution, but for problems with up to N=2000 sub circles, the best known packings obtained from numerical methods [can be found here](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/). ASCII files of the packing values can be freely downloaded for application use. This is an ongoing search, so checking back for updates might be something you'd want to encode.

Note also there is [a little form](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/#Applications) hiding at the bottom of the page which applies the data to the problem of minimising waste for a given size of circle and sub-circle.