# Calculate the diameter of minimum enclosed circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I have n number of circle with diameter and I want to find out diameter of minimum enclosing circle which can fit these n number of circle.

Currently I have used circle packing for same but it not calculating correctly, can someone please suggest any other algorithm to calculate the same?

I am looking for the algorithm which can enclose the circle as below

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a math question, rather than javascript.

Comment: it's not trivial see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23840974/3807365)